# javascript cheerio not retrieving tag

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using cheerio and have had some success in examples found online. however now I am trying my first scrapping project and I don't know why I am not able to retrieve my desired HTML tag.

```
request(url,function(error, response, html){
  if (!error){
     const $ = cheerio.load(html);
     $('.identifier a').filter(function(){
        const data = $(this);
        const link = data.attr('href');
        console.log(`Identifier link: ${link}`);
     });
   }
}
```

when I run this it looks like the tag is simply not found and link is empty. however I also tried 'html' which was found, and 'div' which was not. I have tried adopting various other example structures to find out where things are going wrong without success. Is there something fundamental that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't think it should have any issue. Check whether response html is the one that you are expecting, sometime webpages detect this request as robot and responds with different HTML.

Following code snippet is working, please have a look.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
request('https://cheerio.js.org/', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log($('body > section.page-header > a').attr('href'))
    }
});
```

[image]

Targeting red highlighted area in above image.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I check the HTML that I was retrieving more closely and it seems that it doesn't match what I see when I view the page naturally with the developer tools. Since the links I am looking for don't exist in the scrape, is it likely that the page is deployed via script afterword. 
Is there away that I can used cheerio or other library to get around this and scrape the natural page?

Comment: Sorry about the typos. I realized after the edit timer elapsed.

Thanks

Comment: So were you able to solve your issue? Did my suggestion help in any way??

Comment: From you comment I have found that it is most likely a case of needing to use a headless browser. Thank you